# How i can get value from Binded Textbox in ListView?? (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

```
string test = ((My_ListItem)lvList.Items[0]).m_strValue;
```

I tried to use that code, but I couldn't get `Textbox` user-inputted value, just outputs a default value when I added listview item. how can I get inputted value in binded `Textbox` in `ListView`?

This is my code:

```
public class My_ListItem
{
    public string m_strItemName { get; set; }
    public string m_strValue { get; set; }

    public My_ListItem(string IN_strItemName, string IN_strValue)
    {
        m_strItemName = IN_strItemName;
        m_strValue = IN_strValue;
    }
}
```

**XML Codes are here**

```
<ListView x:Name="lvList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="125"
 Margin="30,243,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="573"
 AutomationProperties.SizeOfSet="-3">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding m_strItemName}" Padding="10"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding m_strValue}" Width="300" />
        </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I have added your updates to the case, you could delete this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need TwoWay Binding for the TextBox `<TextBox Text="{Binding m_strValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="300" />`

Comment: i added 'Mode=TwoWay', it solved perfectly.i appreciate it.